# Swift UI use View in a Protocol (Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements)

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swiftui

I want to use View in a Protocol.

```
protocol Test {
    var view: View { get }
}
```

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
>   has Self or associated type requirements

I just want to do the same thing as with my ViewController. Any idea?

```
protocol Test {
    var viewController: UIViewController { get }
}
```

If I use an associated type, I get the error in my other protocols.

```
protocol Test2: Test { 
    //STUB
}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: `test2: test` should be `Test2: Test`

Comment: The protocol `View` has an `associatedtype` requirement which you're not fulfilling. `UIViewController` works differently as it's a concrete type rather than a protocol with `associatedtype`

Answer (score 16):

[SwiftUI.View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view) is a protocol, and because it uses `Self` (for example, in its [body property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278523-body)), you cannot directly declare a property type as a `View`.

You can define an associated type on `Test` and constrain that type to be a `View`:

```
protocol Test {
    associatedtype T: View
    var view: T { get }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly use the protocol unless you declare it as associated type, but you can use the type erased `AnyView` instead:

```swift
protocol Test {
    var view: AnyView { get }
}
```

Creating an `AnyView` instance might add some noise in the code, however it's easy to create.

Comment: Don't forget to cast the returning view as `return AnyView(Text(""))`

Comment: @Sentry.co this is covered by the last sentence in the answer. BTW, `AnyView(Text(""))` is not a cast, it creates a wrapper/type-erased around the given view.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Cristik's solution:

```
protocol ViewFactoryProtocol {
    func makeView(parameter: SomeType) -> AnyView
}
```